# RPostgres: No applicable method for 'st_as_sfc' applied to an object of class "pq_geometry"

Tags: postgis, r, postgresql, sf

**Setup**

I am using `sf::st_write()` to load data into a PostGIS database. In order to do this, I first had to convert the geometry column of my dataframe from a `character` to a `sfc` vector.

```
df$geom <- st_as_sfc(df$geom)
```

Then, the entire `df` was converted into a `sf` object.

```
df <- st_as_sf(df)
```

Once I have an `sf` object, I then write my data to a PostGIS database.

```
# db connection object
con <- dbConnect(drv = RPostgres::Postgres()
    ,dbname = db
    ,host = host
    ,port = port
    ,password = pw
    ,user = user
    )

# write sf dataframe to db
st_write(dsn = con
    ,obj = df
    ,table = 'table_name'
    ,query = 'INSERT INTO table_name ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'
    ,layer_options = 'OVERWRITE=true'
    ,drop_table = FALSE
    ,try_drop = FALSE
    ,debug = TRUE
    ,append = TRUE
    )
```

**Issue**

The above code works fine, but problems arise once I use the `st_read()` function to pull data from my database.

```
df1 <- st_read(dsn = con
    ,geom_column = 'geom' # name of my geometry column
    ,table = 'table_name'
    ,query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name;'
    )


Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
  no simple features geometry column present
```

I tried calling `dbReadTable()` instead, but ran into related issues. I can read in the data, but I am unable to convert from a `pq_geometry` class to `sfc`.

```
df1 <- dbReadTable(conn = con
    ,name = 'table_name'
    )

df1$geom <- st_as_sfc(df1$geom)


Error in UseMethod("st_as_sfc") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sfc' applied to an object of class "pq_geometry"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `st_read`. I was trying to do the same thing and `st_read` works for me.

Comment: I was able to get this working with `st_read()` after setting `EWKB = TRUE`. The following code ended up working for me:

`st_read(dsn = con, geom_column = "geom", EWKB = TRUE, query = "SELECT * FROM table_name;")`